# Evil mode not working

Tags: evil, package

Using emacs 25.2.2 on Kubuntu 18.04.

Using `list-packages` I installed `evil`. Using `customize-variable` I added `(evil-mode t)` in my `~/.emacs.d/init.el` file.

But still when I restart emacs, there is no trace of evil mode! `list-packages` shows `evil` as an installed package. But there are no evil commands available with `M-x` and `evil-mode` is not enabled anywhere.

What is going on here? How do I set things right?

Comment: What if you don't do it that way but insert `(evil-mode)` in your init file after `(package-initialize)`?

Comment: @wasamasa Thanks! That did work! But why is this happening? I had done everything as mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do I have to add each package to load-path? (or Problem with require 'package in my init file)](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/5828/why-do-i-have-to-add-each-package-to-load-path-or-problem-with-require-packag)

Comment: No idea, I've never used that feature of customize and don't know if it's even supposed to work this way out of the box.